# Best practice for "connecting" json objects

Tags: java, json

My json:

```
{
    "activities": [
        {
                "type": "post",
                "id": "160",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "content": "this is the actual post",
                "timestamp" : "date + time",
        },
        {
                "type": "post"
                "id": "161",
                "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                "content": "this is the actual post",
                "timestamp" : "date + time",


        {
                "type": "comment"
                "id": "162",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "content": "content of the comment",
                "timestamp" : "time + date",
                "secondary_id": "160"

        }    
    ]
}
```

I have 2 types of objects which i have to consider: comment and post.

Every comment is linked to a post with its secondary id. That means if secondary_id is "160" this comment belongs to the the post with the id 160. In my json there could be 50 posts then 1 comment to the 2nd post follwed by 10 more psots and then 6 various comments. Means its not orderd.

So now im trying to figure out how to safe them in my java code to get them linked. Means i need every comment for a certain post. I could do 2 arrays 1 for posts 1 for comments and then search the comments array for every comment with the id 160...161..etc... this would be pretty messy i guess.

Isnt there some pattern or smth like the key is 160 and now give me all the secondary id´s mapped as value for that key or smth?

I hope you know what i mean, kinda of hard to expain. 
Basically what i would need is smth like go through the json check if its post if yes safe it. If its a comment look up the secondary id and match it to the map(or smth) of the right primary id.

Comment: could you structure it like :

{ "posts" : [{ "id" : 5, "comments": [{"id": 6}] }]

Answer (score 0):

First of all when serializing JSON in java there are libraries you can use, [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHomez) for example.

Once you familiar yourself with Jackson, I would create a base class for comment and post that has all the fields that are shared by them.

I would create a [custom deserializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) that after creating a comment object looking up the post object and adding the comment to the post.

Comment: ok thanks. that basically means there is no "standard" java way to do it? And i should use jackson instead of the simplay way (im doing it on andrid, i hope that doesnt matter?)